# Compressing page numbers in BibLatex

Tags: biblatex, citing, page-numbering

In the following example, I would like the page numbers in the citation to be displayed as

> p. 1, 2sq., 7sqq.

or as the German equivalent

> S. 2, 2f, 7ff

How can I achieve this?

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @book{Chomsky1957,
        Address = {The Hague},
        Author = {Noam Chomsky},
        Publisher = {Mouton},
        Title = {Syntactic Structures},
        Year = {1957}}
    }
    \end{filecontents}
    
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}
    \addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
    \begin{document}
    Let me quote some pages here: \autocite[1, 2-3, 7-10]{Chomsky1957}
    \printbibliography
    \end{document}
```

I have looked into the biblatex manual, but so far only found how to set this up for `backref` page numbers.

Comment: There is a feature request open for this at https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/217.

Comment: But thinking about this, why isn't `1, 2-3, 7-10` converted to '1 sqq., 7sqq.'? Does that mean you don't want `biblatex` to compress stuff across comma-separated chunks?

Comment: Yes, since sometimes there might be 3 occurrences of the specific issue, one on p.1, one at the end of page 2 continuing on page 3 and one on pages 7 through 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're so close. `biblatex` includes the commands `\pno`, `\ppno`, `\psq`, and `\psqq` that should provide the output that you're looking for.

Use the following cite command to reproduce your first example.

```tex
\autocite[\pno~2, 2\psq, \ppno~7\psqq]{Chomsky1957}
```

Chomsky 1957, p. 2, 2 sq., pp. 7 sqq.

To translate into the German equivalent, just load the [babel](https://ctan.org/pkg/babel?lang=en) package in your preamble and use the cite command described above.

```tex
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
```

Chomsky 1957, S. 2, 2 f., 7 ff.